# Pass arguments to BackGroundWorker

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I have 3 lists of the following type:

1. folderName : String
2. FTPcount : Int
3. Expectedcount : Int

All are related to each other (based on their index in the list) and I want to pass them as argument to `BackGroundWorker` which reads the folderName while increments FTPcount and  Expectedcount.

How can I pass them (by reference ? ) such that I will be able to see the increments after each one has finished its execution ?

```
        List<string> folderName = new List<string>();
        List<int> Expectedcount = new List<int>();
        List<int> FTPcount = new List<int>();

        foreach (string folder in Properties.Settings.Default.Folders)
        {
            BackgroundWorker bg = new BackgroundWorker();

            bGs.Add(bg);
            Expectedcount.Add(new int());
            FTPcount.Add(new int());
            folderName.Add(folder);

            bg.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(Process_Instiution);
            bg.RunWorkerAsync(new { folderName = folder, Expected = Expectedcount[Expectedcount.Count - 1] as object, FTP = FTPcount[FTPcount.Count - 1] as object });
        }

        while (true)
        {
            bool IsBusy = false;
            foreach (BackgroundWorker bg in bGs)
                if (bg.IsBusy)
                {
                    IsBusy = true;
                    break;
                }

            if (IsBusy)
                Application.DoEvents();
            else
                break;
        }
        //Code to read the various List and see how many files were expected and how many were FTPed.
```

Comment: The fact that you have an `Application.DoEvents()` call means your approach is flawed. :( Might have to do some revamping.

Comment: I know that and I am working on it(can u suggest something for that ?). For now I need help regarding passing the arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [DoWork(Object data) method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f00zz5b2.aspx) that specifics the argument. You will have to cast and it retrieve it from [args Argument Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.doworkeventargs.argument.aspx).

I would either create a object wrapper to pass the data or use an anonymous type.